# including a function from another file ( didn't work = wordpress )

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to include a function outside a plugin folder
i have a folder named

---

url (F://**/wordpress/test/hello.php)
test $inside it there -> hello.php

and i want to call a function inside a plugin in the plugin directory area

url (F://**/wordpress/wp-content/pluginA/plugin-loader.php)
file name -> pluginA-loader.php

---

```
File Name == hello.php
File URL == url (F://**/wordpress/test/hello.php)

//include function from pluginA-loader.php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\wp-content\plugins\pluginA\pluginA-loader.php';
```

after i include the file i tried to call the function like
echo testingfucntion();

there's nothing a blank output

and if i tried this ::

```
function testingfunction(){
// code here 
}
```

**output ::**

cannot redeclare testingfunction();

whats the issue ??

also i tried to including the file like ==> '/'

---

```
// i 
        echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

**output ::**

F://****/wordpress